# Prolog avoid road, city

Tags: prolog

This works perfectly:

```
%connection(Num,Ori,Dest,Distance,RoadNumber)

connection(1,cityA,cityB,20,235).
connection(2,cityB,cityC,23,235).
connection(3,cityB,cityD,30,272).

%road(num,speedlimit)

road(235,50).
road(272,90).
road(273,120).

dest(Z):- 
        A = mystartcity,
    route(A,[Z],0,Path,Cost).

    route(A,[A|Path1],Cost1, [A|Path1], Cost1).
    route(A,[Y|Path1], Cost1,Path, Cost):-
        connection(_,X,Y,Dist,N,E),
        roadtype(N,Vmed,_), 
        CostXY is Dist/Vmed,
        Cost2 is Cost1 + CostXY,
        route(A,[X,Y|Path1],Cost2, Path, Cost).
```

My problem is that I want to avoid certain roads (e.g.: if the road is unavailable because of an accident) and I can't figure it out how.

I think I need something that allow me to change the "status" of the road for available to unavailable, and when it's unavailable, route function should avoid and chose another way. But I can't solve this, I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of closed roads by ID, and use the *not provable* operator, like this:

```
closed(2).
closed(5).

available(X) :- \+ closed(X).

route(A,[Y|Path1], Cost1,Path, Cost):-
    connection(ID,X,Y,Dist,N,E),
    available(ID),
    ...
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight, thanks, it worked :) Mog, I didnt understood you well, bu thanks :) Now ill try a different way without the "+/"

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you could pass as parameters to a `dest/2` predicate your original parameter + a list containing numeros of roads to avoid. Having that, writing a simple `\+ member(ID, ListOfNumsToAvoid)` after the `connection/6` call should do it. Of course, `route/5` would have to become `route/6`.

Then, having coded that, you could propose the 1 parameter version by just calling the general version with the empty list as "avoidance list" parameter.